# How to create the non-optional entity when saving a new entity in core data?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a one to one relationship like so [image]

Its a non-optional relationship. I am trying to figure out how to save a new "Skill".

I have this code:

```
let skill = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Skill", into: managedContext) as! Skill
```

When I look at skill.metaData it returns nil. Also when I save it, I get this:

```
Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1570 "metaData is a required value." UserInfo={NSValidationErrorObject=<SweatNetOffline.Skill: 0x60000366fe80> (entity: Skill; id: 0x6000015428e0 <x-coredata:///Skill/tE588784E-F0D1-4955-9AC2-8296D1F902A42>; data: {
    metaData = nil;
    name = first;
    posts =     (
    );
```

Which basically says its angry that its getting metaData = nil in there. So yeah, how do I create the SkillMetaData object? just `skill.metaData = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "SkillMetaData", into: managedContext) as! SkillMetaData` ? Im worried about stepping on Core Data's toes with however it associates them

Comment: You need to create a skill metadata instance yourself and assign it to the relationship. CoreData will take care of assigning the inverse